# IdHTTPserver: Share ADOConnection

Tags: delphi, connection-pooling, indy

I am creating a simple Indy webserver using **TIdHTTPServer**.  On almost all request the server needs to communicates with a database (via **TAdoConnection**).  Seeing that database connections are somewhat expensive in terms of resources, I would like to create a pooling mechanism to reuse connections; rather than making the connection on each request.

I have searched unsuccessfully for examples.  [This Link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=272073) on Embarcadero Discussion Forums suggests sub-classing descendents of **TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool** and **TIdThreadWithTask**.  But I still cannot get it all together.

Will I need to override the **TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool.NewThread** method and have it return my sub-classed **TIdThreadWithTask** object which in turn would have it's own **TAdoConnection** object?

Does anyone have an example?  Should I not even worry about this and just open the database connection on each request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you manage the pool yourself?

You have a list of connections. It starts empty. Every time a request comes, you look for available connections (connections which are active but not being used). If none are found, you create one and put it in the list, as unavailable. Once the request ends, you set the connection to available.

Been there, done that, do not regret doing it at all! A few points of concern:

- Keep thread safety in mind all times:

  - When you query the list
  - When you query a connection's availability
  - When you set a connection's availability
- From time to time, check if you have too many unused connections available, there might be more than you need, so they must be set to unavailable, removed from the list and then closed.

Comment: That sounds real easy.  So make a class TMyConnectionObject which would have the TAdoConnection object plus a boolean "Active".  And I have a GLOBAL TStringList or TList which stores them.  When OnCommandGet is fired I loop over all my objects to find a "InActive" one.  If there is one I use it; otherwise create and add.  Is there the possibility that OnCommandGet is fired precisely the same time and my processing picks up the same object as available?

Comment: To keep Thread Safety in mind, do I just use a Critical section?

Comment: you got the point. Read my update: there's a chance two connection threads try to access the list at the same time. You have to use threading specific strategies: thread safe list ( http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TThreadList_(Delphi) ), CriticalSection, etc. You might also want to read here: http://www.eonclash.com/Tutorials/Multithreading/MartinHarvey1.1/ToC.html

Comment: Thanks Alot!  Sometimes I let myself get steered by the more "eloquent"/"academic" way when there are much easier methods with just a bit of coding.  FYI - the dockwiki link above needs to have a right paren added in the url.

Comment: I would let ADO manage it's own pooling and not create my own... simply my 2 cents.

Comment: @@Darian Miller.  I have done benchmark test comparisons.  In one situation I create a persistent TAdoConnection connection and create a loop to open/close a query 100 times.  The other test does not use the TAdoConnection, but instead opens the query with the connection string.  I find the method which uses the TAdoConnection to be much quicker.  One drawback is you need to deal with any dropped database connections.

Answer (score 4):

You also have to ensure COM is setup correctly in each thread with a call to the pair: CoInitialize/CoUnitialize

Below is an example unit to include in your project. And in your HTTP server constructor simply create your custom scheduler and Indy will use this instead of the default.

If you do this, then each client thread will be properly initialized for COM and you can also add other items that will be shared by all client threads.

I also create a custom TIdServerContext descendant for each connection (and set the ContextClass property in the HTTP Server constructor as well.)  Different types of servers have different TIdServerContext descendants, but they all utilize the TsoIndyCOMEnabledSchedulerOfThread base thread class as they all do COM of some sort.

I wouldn't put the ADO Connection into the Thread, but rather into the Context...especially if you carry this further into a thread pool.

```
unit ExampleStackOverflow;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes,
  ActiveX,
  IdThread, IdSchedulerOfThreadDefault;

type
  //Meant to be used with a custom TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault descendant
  //to ensure COM support on child threads.
  TsoIndyComThreadWithTask = class(TIdThreadWithTask)
  protected
    //Ensure COM is setup before client connection/thread work
    procedure BeforeExecute; override;
    //Graceful COM cleanup on client connection/thread
    procedure AfterExecute; override;
  end;


  TsoIndyCOMEnabledSchedulerOfThread = class(TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent); reintroduce;
  end;



implementation

procedure TsoIndyComThreadWithTask.BeforeExecute;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  inherited;
end;


procedure TsoIndyComThreadWithTask.AfterExecute;
begin
  inherited;
  CoUninitialize();
end;


constructor TsoIndyCOMEnabledSchedulerOfThread.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  //the whole reason for overriding default scheduler of thread is to setup COM
  //on client threads
  ThreadClass := TsoIndyComThreadWithTask;
  Name := Name + 'COMEnabledScheduler';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I will have to try to digest it.  This is stuff I don't have a good handle on.

Comment: One thing for sure...don't "Suspend" a thread that has an open database connection. As I commented earlier, I would let Microsoft manage the ADO connectivity pool as they do a good job of it already.  I'd create/free a ADOConnection on each Context - it'll be pooled by default by Microsoft.